# Is there any tool that can automatically generate Prolog callable interface from C functions?

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

So basically I am using Prolog to call a large number of C functions using GNU-Prolog.

Here is an example:

```
int add(int a, int b)
{
int res = a + b;

return res;
}
```

If I want to call this function from Prolog code, I need to create this interface:

```
#include <gprolog.h>

 PlBool add_interface(int a, int b, int* r)
{
  *r = add(a, b);
}
```

And In the Prolog code, I need add this :

```
 :- foreign(add(+integer, +integer, -integer)).
```

So I am dealing with a large number of C functions, and manually create these interface one by one would be quite time consuming...

Of course I can write an ad-hoc tool to do this creation(Using CIL probably..), but I just don't want to reinvent the wheel.

So my question is :

Is there any tool that can automatically generate Prolog callable interface from C functions?